# Invalid format string in timestamp

Tags: teradata

I am trying to cast a value to timestamp(0) and insert into a table. The column Port_Out_END_Dttm is timestamp(0). It's giving me invalid format string.

```
,MAX(coalesce(SRC.Port_Out_END_Dttm,cast('31/12/9999 00:00:00' as timestamp FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyyBhh:mi:ss(0)') ))as Port_Out_END_Dttm
```

The entire query is like:

```
sel
,case when  Port_Out_Ver_Phase_END_Dttm in cast ('12/31/9999' as date format 'MM/DD/YYYY') then null else Port_Out_Ver_Phase_END_Dttm end as Port_Out_Ver_Phase_END_Dttm

from
(
sel
,MAX(coalesce(SRC.Port_Out_END_Dttm,cast('31/12/9999 00:00:00' as timestamp FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyyBhh:mi:ss(0)') ))as Port_Out_END_Dttm 
from table
)
```

First i need to coalesce the nulls to a high end date and then again take that date as null
What's wrong over here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to CAST a hard-coded string to a Date/Time/Timestamp, better use a Standard SQL *Date/Time/Timestamp Literal* instead:

```
TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 00:00:00'
DATE '9999-12-31'
TIME '00:00:00'

MAX(COALESCE(SRC.Port_Out_END_Dttm, TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 00:00:00'))
```

Btw, you might need to add a time zone to the literal, otherwise it might be based on your session time zone:

```
TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 00:00:00+00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks slightly off to me.  Try this version:

```
MAX(COALESCE(SRC.Port_Out_END_Dttm,
    CAST('31/12/9999 00:00:00' AS timestamp(0) FORMAT 'DD/MM/YYYYbhh:mi:ss')))
```